# Dialog Flow Webhook JSON Response how to show the Key-values in chat to user

Tags: json, dialogflow-es, webhooks, chatbot

I am getting the webhook response as follow but how to access the different keys in the chat so that i can show information to user in the chat.

```
 {
        "product_data": [
          {
            "Category": "PERFUMES",
            "Collection_EN": "LES EAUX DE POLITESSE",
            "Product_Name_EN": "Fleurs de citronnier ",
            "Size_Volume_TC": "100 ml 淡香精",
            "Sku": "36112392155",
            "Type": "SALES PRODUCT"
          }
        ],
        "source": "webhookdata"
      }
```

Comment: What keys would you like to show? Can you share the code and the setup of your bot?

Comment: I am returning the following Json Response:
{ "fulfillment_response": { "messages": [ { "text": { "text": [ "Hi from web hook"] } } ], 'sessionInfo': { 'parameters': {'service_desk_phonenumber':'17372079207'}} }

Comment: How can I access the context in the chatbot... I am currently using ($session.params.service_desk_phonenumber) to access the updated parameters but it doesn't works..